# how to call grandparent() from child in react.js?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I'm trying to submit a form and directly calling the `loadDataFromServer()` function  so that I don't have to refresh to get the
latest data.
How can I call this method which is directly in scope of `<WebPage />`  ?

### code:

```
<WebPage />
{
  loadDataFromServer:function()
   {

   }

<MainView />
{
<Post> </Post>
<CommentForm  onCommentSubmit={this.loadDataFromServer}/>
}

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
myFunction:function(e)
{

e.preventDefault();
var comm = (React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value.trim());

this.handleCommentSubmit(comm);

React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value = '';
return;
},

render:function(){

return(
<div>
<form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.myFunction}>
    <input className="inputText1" type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Your Comment Here ...." ref="text" /><br /><br />
    <input className="Submit1" type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>

    <input type="search" className="hiddenElement" value={this.props.s} ref="pleaseshow" />
    </div>
);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function `loadDataFromServer()` as props down the tree to the child component where you wish to access it.

```
class Webpage extends React.Component{
  loadDataFromServer(){
    // Load data from server
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <MainView loadDataFromServer={loadDataFromServer}/>
    )
  }
}

class MainView extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <CommentForm loadDataFromServer={this.props.loadDataFromServer}/>
    )
  }
}

class CommentForm extends React.Component{
  myFunction(){
    // Do something
    this.props.loadDataFromServer();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      // Some JSX
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need Flux here. However at the least I'd recommend a slight change to the solution which @naisheel-verdhan proposed -

In CommentForm, instead of naming the prop as "loadDataFromServer", rename it to "onCommentSubmit". This way your CommentForm component doesn't become too tied up with the data fetch tightly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: but still i'm getting " Error: Unable to get property 'props' of undefined or null reference", May be i'll try it using flux or so.. But thanks anyways